# Prove - intersection of subgroups is a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Since I have some similar question to this one, I'll be happy to understand how to solve it.

$G$ is a group and $A,B\le G$. I need to show that $A \cap B \le G$

(If $A, B,$ are subgroups of $G$, I need to show that $A \cap B$ is a subgroup of $G$, too.)

Comment: Im not sure. is that mean that A and B are subgroups of G??

Comment: Yes, that is the usual meaning of $A\leq G$.

Comment: so now that solve all my problems :) thanks

Comment: So, the actual question was, "In group theory, what does the notation $A\le G$ mean?"

Comment: Another possible answer exists here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150061/prove-h-cap-k-is-itself-a-subgroup-of-g-if-h-k-are-subgroups-of-g

Answer (score 2):

**Clarification**
In the context of group theory, if $G$ is a group, then $A \leq G$ denotes "$A$ is a subgroup of $G$"

> $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of a group $G$ (i.e. $A\leq G, B\leq G$). 
> Prove that $A \cap B$ is a subgroup of $G$ (i.e, $A\cap B \leq G$).

**Hint 1**: 
You know that $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$. That means they each contains the ***identity element***, say $e$ of $G$. So what can you conclude about $A\cap B$? If $e \in A$ and $e \in B$, then...? (Just unpack that means for their intersection.)

**Hint 2**: 
You know that $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$. So they are both closed under the group operation of $G$. If $a, b \in A\cap B$, then $a, b \in A$ and $a, b\in B$.  Since $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$, they are closed under the group operation of $G$, so we know it follows that $ab \in A$ and $ab \in B$. So what can you conclude about $ab$ with respect to its containment in $A\cap B$? This is about proving ***closure*** of $A\cap B$ under the group operation of $G$.

**Hint 3**: 
You can use similar arguments to show that for any element $c \in A\cap B$, $c^{-1} \in A\cap B$: 
If $c \in A\cap B$, then $c \in A$ and $c\in B$, so $c^{-1} \in A$ and $ c^{-1} \in B$, again, since $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$. Hence, what can we say about the containment of $c^{-1}$ in $G$? That answer will establish that $A\cap B$ is closed under ***inverses***.

Once you've completed each step above, what can you conclude about $A\cap B$ in $G$?